# Chrome DevTools converts all HEX Colors to RGB

Tags: css, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Recently, Chrome DevTools has begun converting all elements' HEX colors to their RGB values, regardless of whether that HEX color is set in CSS or through the DevTools itself. How to stop that?

I am aware of the hold down <kbd>Shift</kbd> + click the color icon method of converting colors to other formats, but I find this inconvenient. I am wondering if anyone knows how to stop this from happening?

Answer (score 107, accepted):

Step 1, click the gear icon

[image]

Step 2, change `Color format`

[image]

### Original answer

Open Chrome [DevTools](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools) panel:

Click **3 dots** icon at the far right corner, select **Settings**, and in the **Preferences** panel find **Elements > Color format**, select the option you wish to have, **As authored** is the default option.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: This option no longer appears in Chrome 77.0.3865.90, and I'm getting everything converted to RGB.

Comment: As of  78.0.3904.108, it's in *Appearance*, not *Elements* (inside *DevTools* › *Preferences*.)

Comment: After IE its Chrome's turn to turn developers lives complex

Comment: This option seems to currently not be honored :(

Comment: The option is available but Aaron is right, it's not honored. But only if you pick "As authored". You can select "Hex" and it will show the colors as hex values. Not the greatest but at least you can get colors one way or the other.

Comment: This feature seems to be removed now. Hex codes are so much better once your wrap your head around them. Please stop trying to herd us into using RGB

Comment: `Color format` setting doesn't work for me. Still lists `color `properties as `rgb` values

Answer (score 15):

As of Chrome 114.0.5735.199 (July 2023).

1. Hover mouse over color in DevTools, it gives a hint to `Shift-click`.
   [image: Tooltip shows to shift-click]
2. `Shift-click` the color, select the color format you want.
   [image: Menu shows all format options]
3. Select and copy the value in the selected format.
   [image: Selected value in new format]

Comment: Hex is not an option on my side. I have `rgb`, `hsl`, `hwb`, and many others, but the hex code does not appear in the list

Answer (score 2):

Either click of the updown arrow ↕ , there will be different formats from which we can choose from to show the colors or press shift and click the color palette to choose a different format.

[image]


[image]

Answer (score 0):

So there's no positive answer for Chrome/Brave/Edge. If you are on Mac, you can use Safari where you can see the HEX underneath.