# Chrome DevTools converts All HEX Colors to RGB on Computed tab: how to stop?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

On Chrome DevTools the colors that are shown on the Computed tab are always shown as RGB.

If you shift+click on them they change their format but what I want is a more "permanent" configuration that sets all colors to be shown as HEX or to be the same format "as authored".

**Please note this question only relates to the *Computed* tab.** For the styles tab there is already a good answer and a nice configuration on chrome: [Chrome DevTools converts all HEX Colors to RGB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29869426/chrome-devtools-converts-all-hex-colors-to-rgb-how-to-stop) but that configuration don't seem to apply to computed tab. Tested on Chrome Win7/64: Version 45.0.2454.101 m

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On the current version of Chrome that isn't possible, there is no setting for that.

The *Computed* tab is intended to only display the values that come from the browser (you can get the same values using [Window.getComputedStyle()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle)), but having it render the colors in the format of you choice is not unreasonable. Please file a feature request at http://crbug.com/new.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback and I did exactly that: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=537741

Comment: Well lovely, that got closed with status "Wont Fix" because _"you can shift-click to resolve back to hex, etc."_, but now it's not possible to do even that any more (Chrome version 88.0.4324.96)

Comment: I haven't worked on CDT for a long time but suggest reopening the bug and and stating exactly this - there is no working way to change the color format in the computer styles.