# Can't grab colors hex value from dev tools

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

When hovering over a color on dev tools, I get the tooltip that says ""Shift click to change color format", but shift clicking doesn't do that. I even tried to change the default color format to hex value under dev tools preferences but that didnt work as well.

Comment: Mine says "change color format". Is your browser up to date?

Comment: @Rob mine too as well. And it's up to date. If it's relevant, I can shift click to change color format in firefox.

Comment: But that's not what you said it said in your question.

Comment: "Shift click to change color format" is the exact tooltip. I edited my question. @Rob.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/76679837/134761. It shows screenshots of Chrome as of July 2023.